# Erlang, replacing an atom with another one in a list

Tags: erlang

I want to write a function to replace a specific atom with the given atom in an input list. But I want to do it using pattern matching and not using conditional statements. Any idea?

And also I want to write a function to return unique atoms in an expression.
e.g.

Input:

```
[a, b, c, a, b]
```

Output:

```
c
```

Input:

```
[b, b, b, r, t, y, y]
```

Output:

```
[t, r]
```

Comment: It's rather bad form to ask two completely different questions as one question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to replace all instances and keep the order of the list (works with all terms):

```
replace(Old, New, List) -> replace(Old, New, List, []).

replace(_Old, _New, [],           Acc) -> lists:reverse(Acc);
replace(Old,  New,  [Old|List],   Acc) -> replace(Old, New, List, [New|Acc]);
replace(Old,  New,  [Other|List], Acc) -> replace(Old, New, List, [Other|Acc]).
```

For the unique elements filter, you need to keep a state of which elements you have looked at already.

It would be really awkward to implement such a function using only pattern matching in the function headers and you would not really gain anything (performance) from it. The awkwardness would come from having to loop through both the list in question and the list(s) keeping your state of already parsed elements. You would also loose a lot of readability.

I would recommend going for something simpler (works with all terms, not just atoms):

```
unique(List) -> unique(List, []).

unique([], Counts) ->
    lists:foldl(fun({E, 1}, Acc) -> [E|Acc];
                   (_,      Acc) -> Acc
                end, [], Counts);
unique([E|List], Counts) ->
    unique(List, count(E, Counts).

count(E, [])            -> [{E, 1}];
count(E, [{E, N}|Rest]) -> [{E, N + 1}|Rest];
count(E, [{X, N}|Rest]) -> [{X, N}|count(E, Rest)].
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I'm looking for solving your first question would be to use guards, instead of if statements. Using only pattern matching doesn't seem possible (or desirable, even if you can do it).

So, for instance, you could do something like:

```
my_replace([H|T], ToReplace, Replacement, Accum) when H == ToReplace ->
    my_replace(T, ToReplace, Replacement, [Replacement|Accum]);

my_replace([H|T], ToReplace, Replacement, Accum) ->
    my_replace(T, ToReplace, Replacement, [H|Accum]);

my_replace([], ToReplace, Replacement, Accum) ->
    lists:reverse(Accum).
```

**EDIT:** Edited for simplicity and style, thanks for the comments. :)

For the second part of your question, what do you consider an "expression"?

EDIT: Nevermind that, usort doesn't completely remove duplicates, sorry.

Comment: you can switch first and second clauses and remove "when H /= To_replace" - it's quite obvious that if == didnt match then you dont have to replace that element

Comment: also do not mix naming conventions - To_replace is ugly, ToReplace is beautiful.

Comment: Yes, I'm still kind of new to Erlang so I still fumble a bit. Thanks! Will edit

Comment: @keymore: To_replace is not mixing naming conventions, since for atoms and functions and modules and such Erlang uses this_naming_convention it is a matter of taste if you want to keep this naming convention for variables and only capitalize the first letter (note for the non Erlang reader: which is enforced by the language syntax) or to switch to CamelSyntax for variables which has the disadvantage of having totally different naming conventions for variables to the rest of the language.  Either way is some compromise.

Comment: BTW most of the Erlang code avoids this naming thing anyway by having short one-word (or letter) varnames, which is Ok since scope is only one function and these should be short and being set only once also helps.

Comment: @peer-stritzinger there is nothing wrong with using 2 naming conventions for different language elements(atoms, variable names, etc), but using 2 conventions for 1 thing is plain bad and ugly.